# .htaccess rewrite rule not working - how to fix?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect everything with a link of /Drug-Charges/ to simply /

I've been trying both 301 redirects as well as Rewrite Rules and have had no luck.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Drug-Charges/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/Drug-Charges http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've enabled the rewrite engine and everything.

Here's the whole top portion:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ $1.html [R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^Landing-Pages/(.*) County-Resources/$1 [R=permanent]
#RewriteRule ^Practice-Areas/Sex-Crimes/(.*) /$1 [R=permanent]

rewriteRule ^index\.(php|html|htm|asp) http://www.domain.com/ [R=permanent,L] 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Drug-Charges/(.*) /%1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in your rule

- `(.*)` in a `RewriteCond` is accessed as `%1`, not `$1`
- In a .htaccess context, the leading slash is removed from the request URL path

To cut out `/Drug-Charges` from the request URL, you need only

```
RewriteRule ^Drug-Charges/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]
```

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It sends me to www.domain/Drug-Charges/blahblah.html

Comment: @AndrewAlexander It works in my test environment. Do you have other rules or conditions in your .htaccess?

Comment: So many rules, this .htaccess is a mess. I wish it were not the case.

Comment: Also, I need this to affect only the directory /Drug-Charges

Comment: @AndrewAlexander The pattern is `^Drug-Charges/`, so it affects all requests starting with `Drug-Charges`, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, but there is also a file called "Drug-Charges.html" so that could be a problem.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander No, `Drug-Charges.html` doesn't match, because there's no slash `/` in the request. So, no problem here.

Comment: Hrm, I am even testing it in an .htaccess tester, and it SHOULD work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do this kind of redirection without using the `REQUEST_URI` reference.

```
RewriteRule ^Drug-Charges/?(.*)? $1[L,NC,R=301]
```

This rule basically checks if the request starts with `Drug-Charges`, and anything optional following it, and redirects accordingly.

Note that you should remove the `REQUEST_URI` reference altogether.

Comment: It is rewriting it as www.domain.com/.html/blahblah.html